# SublimeText error message: 'NameError: name 'console' is not defined' when trying to print array to console in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sublimetext3, console.log

I've trying to learn to code, specifically using JavaScript currently, and whenever I try to print an array to the console in Sublime 3, I get the error: 'NameError: name 'console' is not defined' - I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, also had a similar error message when I tried this practicing online with Treehouse 'Workspaces'... any help or advice is much appreciated.

I'm sure it's a noob error, but I'm still trying to get the hang of the anatomy of software dev - many thanks!

```
var aeroplanes = [ 'F/A-18F', 'A-10A', 'JH-7B', 'SU-33' ];

eg, using console.log( aeroplanes[2] );
```

I would expect `JH-7B` to be printed to the console

Comment: Why are you using `eg, using` before the `console.log`? try putting the console log on a line by itself

Comment: It's also handy to keep the Javascript documentation open in a separate tab, so you can always copy>paste working examples from there: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log

Comment: The error message `NameError: name 'console' is not defined` looks very suspiciously like what the `python` interpreter would say if you told it to run that line of code. Are you entering this directly into the Sublime console input? (the Sublime console is a `python` console).

Comment: This code worked for me in google chrome. I think the problem was that you put eg, using before the console.log(). var aeroplanes = ['F/A-18F','A-10A','JH-7B','SU-33'];
console.log(aeroplanes[2]);